# Detect button click inside jQuery mobile collapsible

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile and I was trying to add a button inside a collapsible but the problem is that when i click on the button the click event is not fired but instead the block gets uncollapsed or collapsed.

I tried the code below but it didn't work

```js
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page', function () {
    $('#header').on('click', '#start', function (e) {
        alert("click");
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
});
```

```html
<div data-role='collapsible' data-theme='c' data-content-theme='d' data-collapsed icon='arrow-d' data-expanded-icon='arrow-u' data-iconpos='right'>
    <h4 id='header'>
    <input type='button' data-theme='c' value='Demarrer' data-mini='true' data-inline='true' data-icon='mappin' data-icon-pos='top' id='start'/>
    </h4>"
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/XKHVx/ all you need is this `$('#start').on('click', function (e) {
    alert('clicked');
    return false;
});`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it didn't work, the block still collapsing on the button click

Answer (score 0):

that's because your button exists inside the collapsible section. What you can do is prevent the section from collapsing when the button is clicked i.e get the id of the target clicked and if it's the id="start" then e.preventDefault(); so something like this:

```
$('#header').on('click', function (e) {
    var id = e.target.id;
    if(id=="start"){
      alert("click");
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }

});
```